# Al cambiar imagen en input file no la cambia en el input correspondiente

Tags: javascript, html

Expongo mi problema: tengo un input type file en el que al cargar la imagen (capturo evento onchange) y mostrar la previews, hace que aparezca otro input abajo. Y así con todos los que hagan falta.

Mi problema es que cuando tengo varios cargados, si cambio la imagen cargada en uno de los inputs file, solo se cambia la ultima. Entiendo que falla porque tengo un contador que hace que se cargue y muestre el previews en el siguiente input, pero no consigo solucionarlo.

**Lo que intento**: Hay un input, si se carga una imagen y se previsualiza en el label, aparece otro input abajo y así las veces que necesite el usuario, pero que a la vez se pueda cambiar la imagen en uno de ellos y cambie también la preview, en vez de crear uno nuevo.

Os dejo mi código:

HTML donde crea los nuevos elementos:

```
<div id="step4">
    <div class="upload_1">
        <input onchange="filePreview(this)" class="boxForm__inputImg" type="file" class="form-control boxForm__textarea" name="images[]" id="image1">
         <label class="boxForm__labelRadio boxForm__labelRadio--inputImg" for="image1" id="imagenPrevisualizacion"><img class="boxForm__camara" src="images/camara.png" alt=""></label>
       <p class="boxForm__texto boxForm__texto--imagenes">Con imágenes todo es mejor, puedes añádir cuantas quieras</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

EL código JS:

```
var count_divs = 1;

function filePreview(input) {
    var selector_caja = ".upload_" + count_divs + " .boxForm__labelRadio";
var selector_img = ".upload_" + count_divs + " .boxForm__camara";
    console.log(selector_img);
    console.log(selector_caja);
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $(selector_caja).css('border', '0');
            $(selector_caja).css('padding', '0');
            $(selector_img).width('100%');
            $(selector_img).css('border-radius','15px');
            $(selector_img).attr("src", e.target.result); 
        }
    }
    newInput();
}

function newInput(){
    count_divs++;
    var name = "upload_" + count_divs;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add(name);
    div.classList.add("mt-4");
    

    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "file";
    input.classList.add("boxForm__inputImg");
    input.id = "image" + count_divs;
    input.name = "images[]";
    $(input).attr('onchange','filePreview(this)');

    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.classList.add('boxForm__labelRadio','boxForm__labelRadio--inputImg');
    $(label).attr('for',"image" + count_divs);
    label.id = "imagenPrevisualizacion";
    $(div).append(input);
    $(div).append(label);

    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.classList.add('boxForm__camara');
    img.src = "images/camara.png";
    img.alt = "camara";
    $(label).append(img);
    

    $('#step4').append(div);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A ver si he entendido tu problema.

Primera vez respondiendo a alguien así que allá voy.

He probado con tu código y me da error recursivo, D: así que lo he acabado haciendo de cero.

Esto es una versión simplificada de lo que haría yo.
Lo único que hago es clonar el contenedor, vaciar los nuevos campos y quitarle la clase que llama al change.

¡Espero que te ayude!

```js
$(document).on("change", ".boxForm__inputImg", function() {
  //clonamos el contenedor upload
  let contenedorUpload = $(this).parent().clone();

  //vaciamos el input y la imagen para que no las cree con contenido
  contenedorUpload.find("input").val("");
  contenedorUpload.find("img").attr("src", "");
  $("#step4").append(contenedorUpload);

  //Le quitamos la clase para que no vuelva a crear mas inputs
  $(this).removeClass("boxForm__inputImg");
});

//Rellenar el campo de la imagen
$(document).on("change", ".rellenaLabel", function() {
  $(this).parent().find("img").attr("src", $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="step4">
  <div class="upload_1">
    <input class="boxForm__inputImg rellenaLabel form-control boxForm__textarea" type="file" name="images[]" id="image1">
    <label class="boxForm__labelRadio boxForm__labelRadio--inputImg" for="image1" id="imagenPrevisualizacion"><img class="boxForm__camara" src="images/camara.png" alt=""></label>
  </div>
  <p class="boxForm__texto boxForm__texto--imagenes">Con imágenes todo es mejor, puedes añádir cuantas quieras</p>
</div>
```

Edit: Gracias por los comentarios!!

Comment: Cuando publicas una respuesta hay un icono "<>" donde si lo presionas abre una ventana emergente, sirve para insertar código y poder ejecutarlo directamente en SO. Así tu respuesta queda para posteridad.

Comment: Pon el código _en la respuesta_, justamente por el motivo que te indican en el comentario anterior. Piénsalo: si el enlace cae, ¿cómo alguien con un problema parecido verá tu código? La respuesta no es solo para el autor de la pregunta, sino también para los demás que tengan un problema similar más adelante.

Comment: En cuanto al comentario "tampoco sé exactamente cuál es la finalidad ni que es lo que quieres hacer": evita responder cuando necesites aclaraciones del autor de la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: @Yussef Vaaale, así mejor, estaba buscando algo parecido y solo vi los tags de código así que me decante por el codepen, perfecto, Gracias!!